# subtract a constant number from the first column of the rows of each txt file in the directory

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a thousands of txt files in a directory e.g. axk.txt as below

```
1 0.3 0.9 1 0.87 0.95 2 
45 0.5 0.2 12 0.25 0.34 98
23 0.99 0.45 134 0.36 0.2 92
```

I am trying to replace the first element `n` in each row with `n-1`. For example, in this case, axk.txt becomes

```
0 0.3 0.9 1 0.87 0.95 2 
44 0.5 0.2 12 0.25 0.34 98
22 0.99 0.45 134 0.36 0.2 92
```

is there an easy way to do this in bash? I can use a for loop in python but it seems there should be an easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minus one for every first field:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    awk '$1 ~ /^\.?[0-9]/ {$1 = $1 - 1}
         {print}' \
        "$i" > tmp &&
    mv tmp "$i"
done

rm -f tmp
```

This checks the field is numeric (not a string) before modifying it. If you don't need to worry about that, you can remove the awk pattern `$1 ~ /^\.?[0-9]/`. If if `$1` is a string, `$1-1` evaluates to the integer negative one (`-1`).

The awk will also go past zero, to negative numbers. `0.5` becomes `-0.5` and so on. If you don't want numbers to go negative, you can change the whole pattern to just `$1+0 >= 1` (`$1+0` evaluates to zero, if `$1` is a string).

Comment: thanks, this works

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, you can run the following command to subtract 1 from column1

```
awk '{$1=$1-1}1' input_file
0 0.3 0.9 1 0.87 0.95 2
44 0.5 0.2 12 0.25 0.34 98
22 0.99 0.45 134 0.36 0.2 92
```

Answer (score 0):

> thousands of txt files in a directory

You might harness [`-i inplace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) of GNU `AWK` to change many files without much hassle, let `file1.txt` content be

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
7 8 9
```

and `file3.txt` content be

```
10 11 12
```

then

```
awk -i inplace '{$1-=1;print}' file*.txt
```

does change these files to respectively

```
0 2 3
3 5 6
```

and

```
6 8 9
```

and

```
9 11 12
```

Explanation: lessen (`-=`) 1st column (`$1`) value by `1`, then `print`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

> can use a for loop in python but it seems there should be an easier way

You might find [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) built-in module useful, it also does has `inplace` option, however it does just give line as string for you, so if you wish to parse numbers from it you would need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In plain bash, with the assumption the first field is always an integer:

```
while read -r n rest; do echo "$((n-1)) $rest"; done < file.txt
```